# R: how to filter through a data.frame to delete data entries

Tags: r, dataframe, bioinformatics

I have a data.frame, the start of it is below:

```
        gene            snp     pval   best_snp    best_pval
1  ENSG00000007341  rs2932538  5.6007 rs17030613   10.0542
2  ENSG00000064419 rs10488631  7.7461  rs4728142   24.6101
3  ENSG00000064419 rs12531711  7.7449  rs4728142   24.6101
4  ENSG00000064419 rs12537284  4.5544  rs4728142   24.6101
5  ENSG00000064666  rs3764650 12.3401  rs3752246    5.4001
6  ENSG00000072682 rs10479002  5.0141 rs12521868   21.1550
```

As shown, in lines 2-4 the same gene is repeated. For genes that are repeated, I only want to keep the `best_snp` and `best_pval` values for the **first** row that the gene **first** appears, so row 2; and for row 3&4 I want to delete the `best_snp` and `best_pval` values, since it's the same as above.

If a gene is not repeated, then just leave it as it is.

Please keep in mind that the table is much larger than shown and the genes are repeated at random places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if df is your data.frame:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df,.(gene),function(x) {x[-1,c("best_snp","best_pval")] <- NA
return(x)})
```

Comment: The assignment here is attempted for every group which may not be efficient when there are too many groups (out of which there are only a few duplicated entries).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming by *table*, you mean *data.frame*. If so, and if `z` is your data.frame:

```
z[match(unique(z$Best_SNP), z$Best_SNP),]
```

Based on Arun's answer and links to your other question. It sounds like you actually want to keep the rows but replace the duplicates with something (like `NA`?), which could be done with:

```
z2 <- z
z2[duplicated(z2$Best_SNP),c("Best_SNP","Best_Pval")] <- NA
```

Comment: hi thanks. but this deletes the lines with the gene repeated, so it deleted rows 3&4. I want to keep ALL the rows, but just delete the best_snp and best_pvalues for the rows with the repeated gene.

Comment: See update. I've added a solution where they're replaced by `NA`...but that value could be anything.